# SSH to Azure's Kubernetes managed master node

Tags: azure, docker, service, kubernetes, containers

I just deployed a managed Kubernetes cluster with Azure Container Service. My deployment includes a single agent machine over the managed cluster and an Azure disk attached to it for persistent storage.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to ssh this agent server. I read that you should be able to ssh the master node and connect to the agent from there but as I am using a managed Kubernetes master I can't find the way of doing this.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to ssh this agent
>   server.

Do you mean you create AKS and can't find master VM?

If I understand it correctly, that is a by design behavior, AKS does **not** provide direct access (Such as with SSH)  to the cluster.

If you want to SSH to the agent node, as a workaround, we can create **a public IP address** and **associate** this public IP address to the agent's NIC, then we can SSH to this agent.

Here are my steps:

1.**Create** Public IP address via Azure portal:

[image]

2.**Associate** the public IP address to the agent VM's NIC:

[image]

3.**SSH** to this VM with this public IP address:

[image]

Note:

By default, we can find ssh key when we try to create AKS, like this:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was expecting. Thank you for the walkthrough :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you don't even have to create a public IP to that node. Simply add public ssh key to the desired node with Azure CLI:

```
az vm user update --resource-group <NODE_RG> --name <NODE_NAME> --username azureuser --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then run temporary pod with (Don't forget to switch to the desired namespace in kubernetes config):

```
kubectl run -it --rm aks-ssh --image=debian
```

Copy private ssh key to that pod:

```
kubectl cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa <POD_NAME>:/id_rsa
```

Finally, connect to the AKS node from pod to private IP:

```
ssh -i id_rsa azureuser@<NODE_PRIVATE_IP>
```

In this way, you don't have to pay for Public IP and in addition, this is good from security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the below, this will create a tiny priv pod on the node and access the node using nsenter.

https://github.com/mohatb/kubectl-wls